# Printing issues of ABS on a Flashforge Adventure 3 nozzle blocked

Tags: abs, flashforge-adventurer-3

I tried to print in ABS for my first time. I have had my printer for almost 2 years but have only just started to use it and have a total of 28 hours of print time. The job I tried to print was meant to take almost 35 hours to print but I stopped it after 4 hours as there was no material on the build plate. I tried to change the filament back to PLA to do a test print of some other item but was not able to load the PLA due to the nozzle being clogged up. The last of the ABS that was black was coming out of the nozzle a very pale gray. I have bought a new nozzle to reinstall it and try again.

Are there any suggestions as to what caused the nozzle to block and how to stop it from happening again? I was trying to print at 230 °C and a bed temp of 70 °C